# SVN on Linux Mandriva - error when importing the project (svn: E0000013)

Tags: linux, svn, redmine

I created a test project and want to import it into the repository.

I opened the port of SVN -

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3690 -j ACCEPT
```

Then -

```
svnadmin create /home/svn/test
```

Uncommenting the lines -

svnserve.conf:

```
...
[general]
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

passwd:

```
...
[users]
harry = harryssecret
sally = sallyssecret
```

Import the project (project on the same computer where installed SVN):

```
svn import /home/testuser/test/ svn://localhost/home/svn/test/ -m "first import"
```

I enter my username and password (harry), everything is OK.
Files are added, but in the end I get a message -

```
svn: E0000013: Can't open file '/home/svn/test/db/txn-current-lock' : Access denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see, where and when and how you [started svnserve](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html) in order to process svn:// requests